# LINQ's Func<bool> is only called once?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm lost on what keywords to google for... Could anyone please point me to an MSDN page or SO answer explaining why `Foo()` is only called once? Especially since `First` only has a single overload with a predicate. What optimisation is going on here?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = "Foo".First(Foo().Contains); // x 1
            var bar = "Bar".First(c => Bar().Contains(c)); // x 3
            var baz = "Baz".First(c => { return Baz().Contains(c); }); // x 3

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            return "__o";
        }

        private static string Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
            return "__r";
        }

        private static string Baz()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Baz");
            return "__z";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

In addition to accepted and upvoted answers (thanks), running it through ILSpy helped visually clarify the order for me as well.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char foo = "Foo".First(new Func<char, bool>(Program.Foo().Contains<char>));
    char bar = "Bar".First((char c) => Program.Bar().Contains(c));
    char baz = "Baz".First((char c) => Program.Baz().Contains(c));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: fav'd this question.. a string instance resulting from `Foo()` using the extension method of string (`Contains`) as a delegate in the extension method of IEnumerable<char> (`First<char>`) for the instance string of `"Foo"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Foo()` is only called once because the expression you pass to `First()` is `Foo().Contains`.

To evaluate this expression, `Foo()` only has to be called once.

Let's consider the differences between the first and second snippets:

```
"Foo".First(Foo().Contains);
```

Here, `First()` expects a `Func<char, bool>` argument. `Foo()` is called (once) and a member access for `Contains` is performed on the result. The result of that member access is indeed a `Func<char, bool>`, so the code is valid and that delegate is passed to `First()`, which proceeds to invoke it for every character in `"Foo"`. Note that we're done with calling `Foo()` here, since invoking the delegate does not mean we have to evaluate `Foo()` again.

```
"Bar".First(c => Bar().Contains(c));
```

Here, the `Func<char, bool>` passed to `First()` is the lambda expression `c => Bar().Contains(c)`. `First()` will proceed to invoke that delegate for every character in `"Bar"`. The "body" of the lambda expression is executed on every invocation, which results in `Bar()` being called three times.

Comment: Honestly, I tried to elaborate on it, but I always end up repeating myself. I went in and out of edit mode several times now but I can't seem to find a way to express this better.

Comment: This is spot on. The argument to `First` is evaluated once, just like any other argument to any other method. Evaluating the argument means calling `Foo` once. What more can you say?

Comment: @Rawling, that's incorrect.. First just returns the first (zero) item in a collection.. whether the collection is iterated over more than once or not

Comment: @Brett, depends on what you mean by "lazy". `First()` does not use deferred execution, it will start enumerating the source sequence right away. That's normal, since it returns a single element (or throws), not another sequence.

Comment: @Rawling, yeah.. I was totally responding to something I thought you were implying.. it was a misread.. sorry

Comment: @Brett No worries, there's a lot of `Foo` about.

Comment: @Rawling, there is still a point of contention though.. to point it out, I'm going to use the vb.net representation: `"Foo".First( AddressOf String.Contains)` is the equivalent of `"Foo".First(AddressOf Foo().Contains)` right?... you're passing the delegate (pointer).. but that isn't going to actually evaluate "Foo" right?

Comment: @Brett Not too hot on VB, but presumably it can't know what `Foo().Contains` is without evaluating `Foo()`. It could be `"Foo".Contains` or `"Bar".Contains` or `"Brett".Contains`.

Comment: @Rawling, essentially, I'm asking if this evaluates into `String.Contains("F")` .. or rather `Foo(); var foo = String.Contains("F")`

Comment: @Brett, `Contains()` is an instance method, i.e. a method applied to an object instance. `Foo()` has to be evaluated in order to determine the object instance `Contains()` applies to. The resulting delegate is basically a pair (object instance, method to call on it).

Comment: or.. right.. so it becomes `"__o".Contains("F");`.. my mistake

Answer (score 16):

You need to split it to directly see why:

```
var foo = "Foo".First(Foo().Contains);
```

is basically:

```
string foo = Foo();                    // only called once
Func<char, bool> func = foo.Contains;  // = "__o".Contains
var foo = "Foo".First(func);
```

As you see now, `Foo` is only called once and returns "__o". Then the `Func<char, bool>` delegate needed by `First` is taken from that string, which basically means it is a `Contains` on the string "__o" not the method `Foo`, hence "Foo" is only printed once.

In the other two cases you pass in a Lambda-expression which is then called for every character - splitted the same way as above this would be just:

```
Func<char, bool> func = c => Bar().Contains(c);
var bar = "Bar".First(func);
```

Here `Bar` is not called to construct the `Func<char, bool>`, because it is only called "inside" its body, which is why `Bar` is then called on every call of that `Func<char, bool>`.

Comment: ++ but documentation would be great ;)

Answer (score 4):

In all three cases you are passing a function that takes a character and returns a boolean. And in all cases the function will be executed for each character in the string. The difference is how those functions are defined.

```
var foo = "Foo".First(Foo().Contains); // x 1
```

Here you're defining that function as the `Contains` function belonging to the object returned by `Foo()`. To get that `Foo()` needs to be executed just once.

```
var bar = "Bar".First(c => Bar().Contains(c)); // x 3
var baz = "Baz".First(c => { return Baz().Contains(c); }); // x 3
```

In these two cases you're defining a function that ends up calling `Bar()` and `Baz()` in the function call.

Comment: `in all cases the function will be executed for each caharacter in string` is not correct

Comment: `"Foo".First(<Predictate>)` means it will run the predicate function over the First character..

Comment: @Brett, you seem to be confusing things. The predicate passed to `First()` is evaluated for every element of the source sequence, in order, until it returns `true` (then that element is returned) or the source sequence is exhausted (then an exception is raised).

Comment: @Brett, now you've lost me as well. Yup, `First()` is an extension method... so what?